# Simulation and visualization libraries for reinforcement learning in python?

Tags: data-visualization, python, simulation

I am aware of keras, 'block' and a few others Python libraries for neural networks which do Reinforcement Learning among others. But is there a library than can make the task of visualisations easy? Particularly in 3D modelling of agents/environment,Seeing the simulations etc...  I can see a few reinforcement learning videos online that show the simulated agent/environment but either they have made visual models from the ground up or used some other language/technology...(or they are very old). Open AI gym was one such platform where you can place and train your agents but I believe it's more for creating the learning algorithm than for visual simulation and environment.

Comment: Anurag, please [edit] your question, it is very hard to understand. Use proper interpunction and language (Not *n* where you mean *and*. What is *nn*?). Add links and references (e.g. those videos). Also: (what) are you willing to pay? Frankly, I don't even understand what visualizations you mean that are related to reinforcement learning.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at PyBrain, which implements some of the standard benchmark tasks and it allows for the experiments 3D visualization.

Here you can find some examples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEM7YDNonSE

Answer (score 1):

See this link for [testimonials about Psychopy](http://www.psychopy.org/about/testimonials.html), including one about the ease with which links to visualisation software can be made.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at RL Toolkit, which gives examples of visualizations for mountain car and grid worlds.

http://incompleteideas.net/rlai.cs.ualberta.ca/RLAI/RLtoolkit/RLtoolkit1.0.html

Comment: I posted the same question on SO. got openAI gym as a recommended library. Though it has limited environments and agents now, the community is evolving.